# Any alternative for dual listbox control?

Tags: gui-design, design

Is there any alternatives or other approaches - from UI perspective - for dual listbox element?
[image]
In general I'm used to apply the Dual Listbox (as described in the example). The Dual Listbox should serve the user to manage, edit and set two lists of variables. This is a major activity that the users needs to complete. 
It's a new product that we develop and the users are from the financial arena (C Level).
I have a good experience with Dual Listbox for this particular task, but thought maybe there are additional alternatives that works better and or to broaden my set of features to use and embed in future products.

Comment: Could you add a little context to your question?

Comment: Without context we cannot make useful suggestions. To add the needed context you need to include more details about the problem you are facing: What is your dual listbox currently being used for? Why do you think you need an alternative? What kind of product are you working on? What level of expertise do your users have? etc.

Comment: Does this need to work on mobile devices too? That'll make a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that there will be a lot of variables and i think that a list can handle this quite good. It is also a common element so it is easy to understand and work with. 
An alternative could be checkboxes or a multi select, but i guess you would loose the overview quite fast.
Maybe you could add different filters like categories to filter by and the option to add variables via drag and drop.